# If $b^2=p^2+q^2$ and $2b^2=r^2+s^2$ (all values positive integers), then is it necessary that $r=p+q$ and $s=p-q$ (or vice versa)?

Tags: number-theory

Here's the question:

> For positive integers $b$, $p$, $q$, $r$, $s$, if
> $$b^2=p^2+q^2 \quad\text{and}\quad 2b^2=r^2+s^2$$
> then is it necessary that $r=p+q$ and $s=p-q$ (or vice versa)?

I can easily show that it these are sufficient conditions, but can't figure out whether they are necessary.

Comment: Sorry, if I've misunderstood. But I have $b^2 = $ the other expressions, not just $b$, which I think is what your explanation uses?

Comment: No, I am sorry, my example was wrong. Take $b=65, p=63, q=16, r=89, s=23$.

Comment: It might be that $b^2$ can be written as a sum of squares in several ways. So you could have $r=p'+q'$, $s=p'-q'$ where $p',q'$ is a different solution than $p,q$.

Comment: Or even more elementary: $b=5, p=3, q=4, r=5, s=5$.

Comment: Ok thanks, yeah I had noticed the case where $b=r=s$ and should have written that in the question. But I hadn't found any other counter examples like yours, thanks

Comment: Related: [sum of squares function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_squares_function).

Comment: You can prove that if $2b^2=r^2+s^2$ then $r,s$ have the same parity, so can be written as $p+q$,$p-q$ for some $p,q$, and that you then have $b^2=p^2+q^2$.

Comment: @Henry I know but it looked to me (and the OP confirmed!) that they are not interested in *that* particular solution. So we need to look at sums of two squares of *positive* numbers, i.e. cases where $b^2$ can be broken up in at least *three* different ways. The way to achieve that is to make $b$ a product of two (or more) primes of the form $4k+1$.

Comment: @StinkingBishop - so you have given the answer. Multiples also work, so you could have $b=50$ or anything in [OEIS A118882](https://oeis.org/A118882). $b=25$ is the smallest such example with $p_1=20,q_1=15, r_1=37,s_1=17$ or $p_2=24,q_2=7,r_2=35,s_2=5$.  Note that here  $r_1=p_2+q_2, s_1=p_2-q_2$ and $r_2=p_1+q_1, s_2=p_1-q_1$ and and, as Jaap Scherphuis commented, something similar will happen in all other examples.